# Why is mutual information symmetric but conditional entropy isn't?

Tags: information-theory

*Conditional entropy* $H(X|Y)$ tells us how much the average uncertainty about a channel input $X$ is after observing channel output $Y$, and *mutual information* $I(X,Y)$ measures how much information about channel input $X$ can be obtained observing channel output $Y$.

Doesn't this mean that $H(X|Y)$ and $I(X,Y)$ complement each other or tell us the same thing? If so, then since *mutual information* is symmetric $I(X,Y)=I(Y,X)$, shouldn't *conditional entropy* be symmetric as well?

Comment: Consider something more basic. Shouldn't the conditional probability $P(A\mid B)$ have the same value as the conditional probability $P(B\mid A)$? After all, they are dependent on $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(B\cap A)$ respectively and we know that $P(A\cap B) = P(B\cap A) ~ \ldots$

Answer (score 6):

No,because while mutual information tells you how much uncertainty can a random variable $X$ *remove* from another random variable $Y$, the conditional entropy of $X$ given $Y$ tells you how much uncertainty *remained* in X after using the information (given by $I(X;Y)$) that $Y$ gave it.

$H(X|Y)=H(X)-I(X;Y)$

That's why the conditional entropy depends on the value of the entropy before the observation and the mutual information isn't, because it is only the difference ($\delta$) between two entropy states, before and after the observation.

Answer (score 2):

There's a cool [Venn diagram from here.](http://www.ece.tufts.edu/ee/194NIT/lect01.pdf) This shows clearly that $I(X:Y)$ is independent of the order of $X$ and $Y$.

[image]